# Android SDK 21 ignoring imports in AIDL?

Tags: android, aidl

I'm maintaining a project that uses the ancient and unsupported pcgod Mumble client library.  It contains this AIDL file:

```
package org.pcgod.mumbleclient.service;

import org.pcgod.mumbleclient.service.model.User;
import org.pcgod.mumbleclient.service.model.Message;
import org.pcgod.mumbleclient.service.model.Channel;

interface IServiceObserver {
    void onChannelAdded(in Channel channel);
    void onChannelRemoved(in Channel channel);
    void onChannelUpdated(in Channel channel);

    void onCurrentChannelChanged();

    void onCurrentUserUpdated();

    void onUserAdded(in User user);
    void onUserRemoved(in User user);
    void onUserUpdated(in User user);

    void onMessageReceived(in Message msg);
    void onMessageSent(in Message msg);

    /**
     * Called when the connection state changes.
     */
    void onConnectionStateChanged(int state);
}
```

The project built fine with SDK 19.  But after upgrading to SDK 21, it ignores the `Message` import and generates `onMessageReceived(android.os.Message)` instead of `onMessageReceived(org.pcgod.mumbleclient.service.model.Message)`.  Naturally, this breaks all the code that uses it.  I fixed the problem by using the fully-qualified class name in the method specification.

I don't really know anything about AIDL.  Is this a bug in SDK 21, or has the AIDL file been wrong the whole time and SDK 21 just got stricter?

Comment: post your Message Class

Comment: https://github.com/pcgod/mumble-android/blob/master/src/org/pcgod/mumbleclient/service/model/Message.java

Comment: I´d put that code in an external android lib project with the fixed SDK version it works on and include that one in the one with bigger sdk version

Comment: I already have a working solution.  I want to understand the problem.

Comment: Are you compiling the pcgod library code also with the new SDK? This is what @eduyayo was suggesting.Either way, how are you compiling the code? Eclipse, ant, Android.mk? and how is the library included, jar file, or reference project in eclipse?

Comment: The pcgod source tree is copied into the main project.  (I know... I didn't write it.)  It's built with Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience, any custom classes imported in the AIDL interface should exist in the same package as the interface itself.

As to how it worked in the past, I'm not sure, but if you've updated the Build Tools package recently, then it could now enforce or be stricter on this requirement for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Check your build path and ensure the pcclod class is at the top.

project properties
java build path
order and export

When you directly qualify an object you are possibly overriding the build path.